# scrapy.Request not going through

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-request

The crawling process seems to ignore and/or not execute the line `yield scrapy.Request(property_file, callback=self.parse_property)`. The first scrapy.Request in `def start_requests` goes through and executed properly, but not one in `def parse_navpage` as seen here.

```
import scrapy

class SmartproxySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scrape_zoopla"
    allowed_domains = ['zoopla.co.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        # Read source from file
        navpage_file = f"file:///C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/spiders/html_source/navpage/NavPage_1.html"
        yield scrapy.Request(navpage_file, callback=self.parse_navpage)

    def parse_navpage(self, response):
        listings = response.xpath("//div[starts-with(@data-testid, 'search-result_listing_')]")

        for listing in listings:
            listing_url = listing.xpath(
                "//a[@data-testid='listing-details-link']/@href").getall()  # List of property urls
            break
        print(listing_url) #Works

        property_file = f"file:///C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/spiders/html_source/properties/Property_1.html"
        print("BEFORE YIELD")
        yield scrapy.Request(property_file, callback=self.parse_property) #Not going through
        print("AFTER YIELD")

    def parse_property(self, response):
        print("PARSE PROPERTY")
        print(response.url)
        print("PARSE PROPERTY AFTER URL")
```

Running `scrapy crawl scrape_zoopla` in the command returns:

```
2022-09-10 20:38:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/spiders/html_source/navpage/NavPage_1.html> (referer: None)
BEFORE YIELD
AFTER YIELD
2022-09-10 20:38:24 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Both scrapy.Requests requested local files and only the first one worked. The files exist and properly display the pages and in case one of them does not the crawler would return error "No such file or directory" and likely be interrupted. It seems here the crawler just passed right through the request, not even gone through it, and returned no error. What is the error here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a total shot in the dark but you could try sending both requests from your `start_requests` method. I honestly don't see why this would work but It might be worth a shot.

```py
import scrapy

class SmartproxySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraoe_zoopla"
    allowed_domains = ['zoopla.co.uk']

    def start_requests(self):
        # Read source from file
        navpage_file = f"file:///C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/spiders/html_source/navpage/NavPage_1.html"
        property_file = f"file:///C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/ScrapeZoopla/spiders/html_source/properties/Property_1.html"
        yield scrapy.Request(navpage_file, callback=self.parse_navpage)
        yield scrapy.Request(property_file, callback=self.parse_property)

    def parse_navpage(self, response):
        listings = response.xpath("//div[starts-with(@data-testid, 'search-result_listing_')]")

        for listing in listings:
            listing_url = listing.xpath(
                "//a[@data-testid='listing-details-link']/@href").getall()  # List of property urls
            break
        print(listing_url) #Works


    def parse_property(self, response):
        print("PARSE PROPERTY")
        print(response.url)
        print("PARSE PROPERTY AFTER URL")
```

---

## Update

It just dawned on me why this is happening.  It is because you have the `allowed_domains` attribute set but the request you are making is on your local file system which naturally is not going to match the allowed domain.

Scrapy assumes that all of the initial urls sent from `start_requests` are permitted and therefore doesn't do any verification for those, but all subsequent parse methods check against the `allowed_domains` attribute.

Just remove that line from the top of your spider class and your original structure should work fine.

Comment: Yes it did work but any idea as to why scrapy.Request in `def parse_navpage` would not work? Might it be because the callback is not self parsing?

Comment: @Andrea... Yes I do know why.  It literally just dawned on me why this is happening.  I will update my answer.